# Laravel - DateTime error after updating composer?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I updated the composer just now, and I think it messed something up, I cannot access any pages, and it just throws this error, but I'm not even using DateTime anywhwere!? and that timestring changes if I refresh the page. please help.

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2018-03-11
>   18:11:02.-338100) at position 24 (1): Unexpected character

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVvDW.jpg)

Comment: Try clearing browser's cache. And this might be it! https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/23464

Comment: It's a reported Carbon bug I believe. [Issue](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/1184)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Carbon issue with 32bit OS/PHP build, fixed in 1.24.2:
https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/releases/tag/1.24.2

Answer (score 0):

Write in console:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

If you also get error: INVALID REQUEST (Unexpected EOF) from time to time, built-in server with router script logs this kind of stuff :

[Thu Dec 8 13:39:29 2011] 127.0.0.1:50358 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)

This happens quite randomly, whatever the script has a close tag or not, whatever it has a blank line after close tag or not.

More: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60471

So generate key again and clear also config cache to be sure:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Then all should work perfectly

Good luck!

Comment: Done that, it works first time, but then I try go to another page and get the same error again, in the console where i run php serve I also get error: INVALID REQUEST (Unexpected EOF)

Comment: Look now, i extended my answer!